# How to allow javascript to flow over other page elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I am trying out d3.js. All I have is a very simple title (bootstrapped html) and the d3.js graph. I would like the title to be visible over the graph, whereas at the moment the container covers it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Graph/index</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<div class="container-full">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center v-center">
          <h1>My.app</h1>
          <br>
          <form class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
              <input type="text" class="center-block form-control input-lg" title="Enter you email." placeholder="My app">
              <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">OK</button></span>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- /row -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center v-center" style="font-size:39pt;">
          <a href="#"><i class="icon-google-plus"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>  <a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="icon-github"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="icon-pinterest"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <br><br><br><br><br>
</div> <!-- /container full -->
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <%= yield %>   
<%= javascript_include_tag('graph') %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS apply the following attribute to your title:

```
z-index: 99;
```

z-index is a style property that defines the stacking order of elements. The higher the index, the further forward it stacks. For example an element with z-index 1 is in front of any elements without a z-index defined, but behind an element with z-index of 5.